# Consistent way to set TinyMCE text area content via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm desperately trying to figure out a consistent application for this code. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Setup:**
There is a TinyMCE text area on my form.

**Desired Outcome:**
User clicks a button and imports dynamic content into said field via jQuery, regardless of the editor mode.

**Issues:**
1) The user will likely NOT be clicking into the text area ahead of time, so using "setContent" doesn't work (because it has not yet been initialized)
2) If I manually initialize it, its behavior is unpredictable. setContent seems to only work if the editor is in Visual Mode, and it butchers any HTML tags within the content. Furthermore, the user has to click "text" or "visual" multiple times before it starts behave normally when toggling modes.
3) If I set it via a typical $('#field').val(data), it only works when the editor is in text mode.

I've tried searching here and Google exhaustively and all of the solutions I've encountered don't seem to account for varying user behavior (i.e. if the user doesn't click into the visual mode beforehand, if the editor is left in text or visual mode, etc. etc.)

Am I losing my mind, or is there seriously not an out-of-the-box solution for setting content via jQuery that produces consistent, quality results??

Comment: I've always had good results when initializing tinymce on content that is already there. Is it possible for you to insert your content into the `textarea` and then initialize?

Comment: That's an option in some cases, but unfortunately not guaranteed. Basically, there's a "Contract Scope" field with three template options. So if a user selects the templates without ever clicking into the text field, I could go that route. But if a user starts typing something and then changes their mind, it would already be initialized.

Comment: I'm kind of baffled that there's no trigger to sync the values similar to how Chosen dropdowns can rebuild their option listing using .trigger("chosen:updated")...